# Two questions about Li-Yau-Hamilton estimate

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

This question is from my question on [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790329/two-questions-about-li-yau-hamilton-estimate/1796194#1796194).

Picture below is from [231 page](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947) . For to prove $Q\ge 0$ on $M \times (0,T)$, 
$(\partial_t -\Delta)Q \ge 0$ and $Q\ge 0$ are  needed to prove.But I can't see $Q\ge 0$ when $t=0$.

Besides, how to ensure 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& (\partial_t -\Delta) W_a =\frac{1}{t}W_a \\
& \nabla_aW_b=0
\end{aligned}
\right.~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& (\partial_t-\Delta)U_{ab} = 0 \\
& \nabla_aU_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}(R_{ab}W_c-R_{ac}W_b)+\frac{1}{4t}(g_{ab}W_c-g_{ac}W_b)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
have solutions ? And $W_a$ and $U_{ab}$ are arbitrary , how to explain it ? (It is enough that proving the basis meets the equations ?)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you look at proper textbooks on the Ricci flow (e.g. one of those by Ben Chow et al.) or the original paper of Hamilton? This reference only gives a sketch, which seems to be extremely poorly written.

Comment: @YangMills   Do you mean Bennett Chow's  Hamilton's Ricci Flow  ?

Comment: The book by Chow-Lu-Ni "Hamilton's Ricci Flow" has a detailed sketch of the proof. For a complete proof see either Hamilton's original paper, or the book "The Ricci Flow: Techniques and applications, part II: analytic aspects" by Chow-Chu-Glickenstein-Guenther-Isenberg-Ivey-Knopf-Lu-Luo-Ni.